# Trying to use underscore filter to extra a specific attribute set

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a data set in a backbone model like below.

```
    “cal":[
{
  "event”:"com”,
  "method":”phone”
},
{
  "event":”morning”,
  "method":”phone”
},
{
  "event”:"afternoon”,
  "method":”phone”
},
{
  "event”:"evening”,
  "method”:”phone"
},
{
  "event”:"com”,
  "method":”SMS"
},
{
  "event”:"morning”,
  "method":”SMS”
},
{
  "event”:"afternoon”,
  "method":”SMS”
},
{
  "event”:"evening”,
  "method":”SMS"
},
{
  "event”:"com”,
  "method":”Email"
},
{
  "event”:"morning”,
  "method":”Email"
},
{
  "event”:"afternoon”,
  "method":”Email"
},
{
  "event”:"evening”,
  "method":”Email"
}
]
```

I want to filter through using _filter

```
 _.filter(cal, function(item){
           console.log("item = ", item);
        });
```

but need to extract all the parent objects that have the event value of "morning" in them.

Not sure how to do that using the filter method ? Presuming there isn't a better way to do it using another method in underscore.

Comment: Please post actual, syntactically valid code - i.e. no smart quotes but normal JS object literal notation (curly braces etc.)

Comment: That would help my answer thanks.

Comment: What do you mean *parent objects* ..? I don't see any nested objects...

Comment: @ericb You still have smart quotes in there. This makes it impossible for others to copy and use your sample data to test their answers, forcing them to type it manually, which is rude on your part. Work with the people who want to help you, not against them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd prefer an even simpler alternative, try:

```
var mornings = _.findWhere(cal, { event: 'morning' });
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into the same as I did here is the answer.

```
var mornings = _.filter( cal, function(item){
                return item.event == 'morning';
            });
```